# Tomcat Not Starting

Tags: tomcat

My WebApplication is hosted on apache tomcat and when i try to access the website it just keeps on loading and no web-page is returned.

When I checked the apache-tomcat directories there were heap dumps in those directories.

Then I re-started my server and after the re-start the web-appliaction is not working.

When I checked the catalina logs I found these statements:

```
SEVERE: Catalina.start
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: The socket name is already in use.:8080
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1019)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:578)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:432)
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2281 ms
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.25
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
INFO: XML validation disabled
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/sun/student0/webapps/WEB-INF/lib/j2ee.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/sun/student0/webapps/WEB-INF/lib/javaee.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/sun/student0/webapps/WEB-INF/lib/javax.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/sun/student0/webapps/WEB-INF/lib/servlet.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/sun/student0/webapps/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-5.5-servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
2012-10-19 07:27:06 - Database - Driver: com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver  URL: jdbc:sybase:Tds:Student:2025/student  User: studentweb
2012-10-19 07:27:06 - Connection Pool - Min: 1  Max: 1  Days: 1.0
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:07 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.25/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/j2ee.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:07 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.25/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/javaee.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:07 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.25/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/javax.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:07 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.25/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/servlet.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:07 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.25/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-5.5-servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:08 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.net.BindException: The socket name is already in use.:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.initEndpoint(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:298)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.startEndpoint(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:313)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol.start(Http11BaseProtocol.java:151)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1090)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.net.BindException: The socket name is already in use.:8080
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1097)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Oct 19, 2012 7:27:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3489 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already have port 8080 bound , change the tomcat port and try restarting

1) Locate server.xml in {Tomcat installation folder}\ conf \

2) Find following similar statement

```
 <!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8180 -->
    <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

or

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

change 8080 to any other port of your choice , save the file and then start tomcat.

Comment: I did the change and changed the port to 8081 and restarted the server and the application works but if I change back the port to 8080 and restart the webapplication does notwork.

Comment: before you can make 8080 work , you have to stop the service Running on port 8080 , in your case I am doubting it is Oracle XE or ORacle 10g/11g . Also if the answer worked please accept it